# beacon proximity detector not working in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I'm building an app which detect Beacon device proximity using locate beacon app in iPhone 6 and my app in iPhone 7 but app is unable to detect the Beacon transmitter. I have entered correct UUID and Major Minor number but it is not working. I'm running on iPhone 7 with iOS 13.5 and iPhone 6 with iOS 12 it is not detecting.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var distancestatuslbl: UILabel!
    var locationmanager: CLLocationManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        locationmanager = CLLocationManager()
        locationmanager.delegate = self
        
        locationmanager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
       
        if status == .authorizedAlways
        {
            print("Allowed any time")
            startScanning()
        }
        
        else if status == .authorizedWhenInUse
        {
            print("Allowed only during run time")
            startScanning()
        }
    }
    
    func startScanning() {

        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self)
        {
             let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")
            let majornumber: CLBeaconMajorValue = 123
            let minornumber: CLBeaconMinorValue = 456
            
            let beaconregion = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: uuid!, major: majornumber, minor: minornumber, identifier: "com.mybeacon")
            
            locationmanager.startMonitoring(for: beaconregion)
            
            print("Started scanning") 
        }
    }
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
       if region is CLBeaconRegion
       {
        if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable()
        {
            locationmanager.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)
        
            print("Starting ranging...")
            
        }
       }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        
        let nearestbeacon = beacons.first!
        
        switch nearestbeacon.proximity {
        case .near:
            distancestatuslbl.text = "Near"
            break
            
        case .immediate:
            distancestatuslbl.text = "Immediate"
            break
        
        case .far:
            distancestatuslbl.text = "Far"
            break
        default:
            print("sdf")
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: When you run the code, which debug lines get printed?

Comment: Allowed anytime and Started scanning

Comment: Didenterregion() is not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to call `startScanning()` in `viewDidLoad`.  As written, it is only called after permission is first granted meaning it only starts the first time you run the app and grant permission, then never again.

Also, check that the beacon actually is transmitting by running the Locate app on the same phone as your app.  Does Locate detect?